# Gemfile updated, error doing bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, rubygems, gemfile

I´m totally lost so i will try to explain my problem. 
Actually im reading the book Ruby on Rails tutorial. I´m actually installing all the environment to start learning this language.

The book asks me to update the Gemfile, and add this

```
  group :assets do
    gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.4'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
    gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
    end
```

So i delete my old gem sass-rails, my old gem coffee-rails and my old gem uglifier.
After doing this the book asks me to save it and run Bundle install on my console.

After doing this i get this message:

```
You have requested:  
    coffee-rails = 3.2.2

The bundle currently has coffee-rails locked at 4.0.1.
Try running `bundle update coffee-rails`
```

So i´m totally lost, and i have no idea what i´m doing cause im only following the steps from the book. Someone could help me and tell me what i should do here? Why the book is asking me to do all this if then it does´t work?

Comment: Looks like you're reading a book written for Rails 3 while working on a Rails 4 app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have already done a bundle install on a newer (probably without the version requirement) of coffee-rails and that is currently locked down in your Gemfile.lock file.

Do what it says and run `bundle update coffee-rails` to update your Gemfile.lock file to the version you specify

Comment: It says: 

Could not find gem 'jquery-rails (= 2.0.0) ruby' in the gems available on this
machine.

Comment: sounds like you are using Rails 4, not Rails 3 which is causing potential conflicts.  Could you paste/gist/link to your full Gemfile

Comment: Yes, as I thought, you are using Rails 4 but trying to lock down to versions of other gems that dont work with Rails 4.  You need the newer versions of coffee-rails, sass-rails ,not the old Rails 3 versions

Comment: so i keep using my old Gemfile and ignore that part of the book that ask me to do that?
Heres a link of the original GemFile
https://github.com/pkrmf/first_app/blob/master/Gemfileold

Comment: Yes, your tutorial is just incorrect and out of date.  It also leads me to believe that they will talk about Rails 3 things that may now have changed in Rails 4, just so you know and are aware